# How to set default filter(exact) of p:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter

I have a column in my datatable which is using the exact-filter function of Primefaces.

I need to set the default filter of the datatable on **foo1**, but it is setting on **all**.

```
<p:column filterMatchMode="exact"
                    filterOptions="#{bean.filterFooOptions}"
                    filterBy="#{row.foo}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Foo" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.foos}" />
                </p:column>
```

and the method to get the filter options in my bean:

```
  public SelectItem[] getFilterFooOptions() {
        if (items == null) {
            items =
                    new SelectItem[] { new SelectItem(Foo.foo1.name()),
                            new SelectItem(Foo.foo2.name()), new SelectItem("", "all")};
        }
        return items;

    }
```

Comment: and if you try `items  = new SelectItem[4];items[0] = new SelectItem(Foo.foo1.name());items[1] = new SelectItem(Foo.foo2.name());items[2] = new SelectItem("", "all"); ` ?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I get a NullPointer, if use this

Comment: and this ? `items = new SelectItem[4];items[0] = new SelectItem(Foo.foo1.name(),Foo.foo1.name());items[1] = new SelectItem(Foo.foo2.name(),Foo.foo2.name());items[2] = new SelectItem("", "all");` , also where do you get the nullpointer?

Comment: why do you set SelectItem[4]? If I set SelectItem[3], I don't get the Nullpointer anymore, but it is still default filtered by "all". I'll try your second solution now

Comment: same in second solution, default filter  is still "all"